# Disabling Inappropriate Buffering Perl

Tags: perl

I was working with a file parser in perl that prints the name of every file it processes. But i noticed that these print outputs appeared out of order which got my attention. After further digging, i found out that this is because, Perl is using Buffering and releases these print statements to the output only when the buffer is full. I also learned that there is a work around by ***"making the filehandle hot"***. Whenever you print to a hot filehandle, Perl flushes the buffer immediately. So my question is :

**Are there any consequences of "making the filehandle hot" ?**

**Does leaving the buffer to get filled up before flushing vs flushing immediately have any effect on performance ?**

Comment: Yes it has effect on performance; buffering is all about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perl uses different output buffering modes depending on context: Writing to files etc. buffers in chunks (this is important for performance), while a handle is flushed after each line if perl has reason to believe that the output goes to a terminal. `STDERR` is unbuffered by default.

You can deactivate buffering for the currently `select`ed file handle by setting the special `$|` variable to a true value. However, this is better expressed as:

```
use IO::File; # on older perls
...

$some_file_handle->autoflush(1);

print { $some_file_handle } "this isn't buffered";
```

which has the advantage that you don't have to use the annoying `select` function for handles other than `STDOUT`. Why is this method called `autoflush`? The file handle is still buffered, but the buffer is automatically flushed after each `print` or `say` call.

Careful: The `autoflush` method won't work on truly ancient perls where file handles aren't objects yet. In that case, do the `select` dance:

```
my $old_fh = select $my_$fh;
$| = 1;
select $old_fh;

print { $my_fh } "this isn't buffered";
```

(`select` returns the currently selected file handle).